# Apache (Xampp) doesn't start

Tags: php, apache, command, xampp, line

I have a problem with Xampp, I installed the PHP command line thus:

```
curl -s php-osx.liip.ch/install.sh | bash -s 5.6
```

However, Apache don't start by Xampp. I will deinstall the PHP command line to start Apache, because I don't find any way to deinstall the command line and start Apache.

Errors will be displayed, if I put the code in the terminal:

```
Code: tail -2 /Applications/XAMPP/logs/error_log
```

Result:

```
[Tue Nov 25 13:55:53.030798 2014] [core:notice] [pid 1533] AH00094: Command line: '/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin/httpd -E /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/logs/error_log -D SSL -D PHP'
[Tue Nov 25 17:12:33.235502 2014] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 1533] AH00169: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
```

Comment: Can you tell us your OS version??

Comment: Yes, Yosemite 10.10.1

Comment: Usually errors are more specific than this. On OS X you have a native Apache, I wonder if you have a port conflict? How did you install the Apache command line?

Comment: No, all ports are not already in use.

Comment: This is not the Apache Command Line, this is the PHP Command Line, i haven't a idea. That is my big Problem that i have..

Comment: OK, what does "I installed the PHP command line" mean? How did you do that? Homebrew? Macports?

Comment: I have put a Code in the Terminal:

Comment: The Code:

curl -s http://php-osx.liip.ch/install.sh | bash -s 5.6

Comment: And the Website where i have the code: http://php-osx.liip.ch/

Comment: Are you trying to update the php version from 5.3 to 5.6, right??

Comment: That was not my target, because i have do this and yes it's right.

Comment: And, if i write in the Browser "localhost", there is a text named "It works!".

Comment: Why are you using the installer from php-osx.liip.ch when you also are using XAMPP? XAMPP will do all this for you, and the version of PHP it supplies is up to date. You may need to uninstall both, then re-install XAMPP on it own.